# MVC Razor Engine Renderpartial View From Custom Location and also need to support fallback search location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to render the Partial view from Custom Locations but also want to support the fallback search location if custom location not found. How do I achieve this in MVC5.

```
@HTML.Partial("~/Parent/Child1/1.cshtml")
```

If it found here then OK. But if not then it should search in default location.

```
@HTML.Partial("~/Parent/Default/1.cshtml")
```

I did some thing like this but not works.

```
  var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().First();
        razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats.Concat(new string[]
        {
            "~/Parent/Default/{0}.cshtml"
        }).ToArray();
        razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats = razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats.Concat(new string[]
        {
            "~/Parent/Default/{0}.cshtml"
        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: What kind of "fallback search location" you want? Is that some attempts to seek entire project directory for requested view page?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I just want if view not found here @HTML.Partial("~/Parent/Child1/1.cshtml") then it should look here ~/Parent/Default/1.cshtml. Here Default is fixed.

Comment: Try adding `"~/Parent/Child1/{0}.cshtml"` into `PartialViewLocationFormats` and use `@Html.Partial("1")`. Instead of using relative path, try using partial view name - the view engine will automatically searches for defined locations.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, that is my problem, I can not user relative path. I have to user absolute path and also want search locations also.

Comment: It's a pity, because ASP.NET MVC has great fallback mechanics for views, even in our very complex application, it covers all our needs. Of course, the "Default" folder is called "Shared", and in some cases, we just create simple "proxy" views, which just do the one-liner `@Html.Partial("_SomeOtherView")` to get default views running and the "Shared" folder is not what we want

Comment: @thomashaid.com, Yes asp.net MVC works great when we render using just by partial view name. Here I am talking about specific path only. If specific path not found then in default location which is also different location then shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by overriding the FindPartialView method of RazorViewEngine.
Here is my solution that works for me.

```
public class CustomeViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, partialViewName, null);

        if (result.View == null && partialViewName.StartsWith("~/Parent"))
        {
            var pathArr = partialViewName.Split('/');
            pathArr[pathArr.Length - 2] = "Default";
            partialViewName = string.Join("/", pathArr);
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
        return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
    }
}
```